# Run loop once per event

Tags: objective-c, loops

How do i run a loop once per event? Consider the following code:

```
-(void)didloadFromCCB {
    BOOL add = YES;
    if (bought_coins && add)
    {
        coins = coins + 5;
        add = NO;
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that coins are added to the player every time the game restarts after the player bought the coins ONCE. I want the coins to be added ONLY when the player buys the coins each time and not every time the game loads from CCB. How should i change the code to make it work?

Comment: Can the player buy coins multiple times per game?

Comment: Yes but the loop must run only when the player buys the coins.

Comment: Show us the source code of the loop.

Comment: When does `didLoadFromCCB` get called?  How does `bought_coins` get set?  What is a CCB?

Comment: @user3623891 I edited your indentation to make it more readable. I also swapped out `TRUE` and `FALSE` for `YES` and `NO`, the correct values for a variable of type `BOOL`.

Comment: This is the source code of the loop. didloadFromCCB gets called when the player starts/restart the game. bought_coins get set when the player press a button to buy. CCB is a CocosBuilder file.

Comment: There is no loop here.  A loop involves `for`, `while`, `goto`, or recursion.

Comment: I should say if condition. Every time the game loads, coins will be added after the player bought the coins. Since bought_coins is true, coins will be added whenever the game loads. Do you have a way to make the coins add only when the player buys?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `add` a static variable, so that its value persists across calls to `didLoadFromCCB`:

```
-(void)didloadFromCCB {
    static BOOL add = TRUE;
//  ^^^^^^
    if (bought_coins && add)
    {
        coins = coins + 5;
        add = FALSE;
    }
}
```

If you need to subsequently reset `add` (e.g. when coins are purchased again) then you could move it outside of the function, e.g.

```
static BOOL add = TRUE;

-(void)didloadFromCCB {
    if (bought_coins && add)
    {
        coins = coins + 5;
        add = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use static bool, the code can work after the player bought the coins once. If the player buys the coins again, the coins are not added. Any solution?

Comment: You could move `add` out of the function and then reset it to TRUE when the player buys the coins again.

Comment: If i move static bool outside of didloadFromCCB, the coins are not added when the player buys the coins the first time?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference to what happens the first time.

Comment: Actually it does not work if static bool is outside of didloadFromCCB. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Not without knowing more about what you're trying to do and how the rest of your code fits together - it sounds like you might need to take a step back and do a little more thinking about your requirements and your overall code design, rather than just trying to tinker with the existing code until it works.